# Missing data points while writing from a file using cURL in InfluxDB

Tags: database, http, curl, influxdb

I was trying to insert data into an InfluxDB database as per this documentation by executing the command `curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=myDB' --data-binary @data.txt`. Where *data.txt* is a file containing more than 50 points.

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: 93487c9c-a1a8-11ea-80bd-9829a645199e
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.8.0
X-Request-Id: 93487c9c-a1a8-11ea-80bd-9829a645199e
Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 12:33:18 GMT
```

I was only able to write 50 points to `myDB` and I thought it was due to `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue`. After some googling, I landed on [this](https://gms.tf/when-curl-sends-100-continue.html) article and as per that I modified and executed the above command like `curl -H 'Expect:' -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=myDB' --data-binary @data.txt`

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: 54b34ebd-a1bc-11ea-80ca-9829a645199e
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.8.0
X-Request-Id: 54b34ebd-a1bc-11ea-80ca-9829a645199e
Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 14:54:43 GMT
```

I was successfully able to bypass `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` but still, I am only writing 50 points to `myDB`.

I am an absolute NOOB to **InfluxDB** and **cURL**

Answer (score 0):

Recently I figured out the issue. The problem is with the contents of `data.txt` file. I am writing each data point without a `timestamp` and because of that all the measurents was allotted with the same `timestamp`.

E.g.,

```
temperature,tag=computer node="cpu",value=38
temperature,tag=computer node="gpu",value=45
temperature,tag=computer node="ram",value=40
```

If I had the above three measurements in file `data.txt` without `timestamp` the InfluxDB will only accept the final value (overwrites previous values since all are having same `timestamp`).

Since I am NOOB to this, I wasn't aware of all the properties of InfluxDB.